# Is there a difference between array[0] vs array.first?

Tags: swift

I'm wondering if there is a difference between `array[0]` vs `array.first?` If not which way do you prefer. I feel like `array.first` is more clear, but I'm wondering if there is a difference and which way Swift programmers prefer?

Comment: Please research your question before asking. The documentation explains this. If you *did* research, please include that in your question, so that it shows research effort and is able to address a more specific question you have.

Comment: If you need only the first element just use first but if you need to iterate through your array elements better to get its indices.

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I prefer using `array.first`. If there are no elements in the array, the `array[0]` will cause a crash, but `array.first` will not. `array.first` returns nil.

For `array[0]`, the `if !array.isEmpty {}` check should be applied first.
For `array.first`, it returns an *optional* value, the `if value == nil` check also needs to be applied after. But it's more convenient if the receiver is also *optional*, like `UILabel`'s text property: `aLabel.text = array.first`

Comment: Just because something doesn't crash doesn't make it "better." Many would argue that silent failure is much worse than loud failure, because it keeps you from debugging efficiently.

Comment: Yes, you are right if you consider it that way. I change the answer to be more personal.

Comment: Don't use the count property to check if the array is empty. Use the proper property `isEmpty`

Comment: @4castle using `.first` doesn't necessarily imply silent failure, although that's well within the possibilities. If you're aiming for safety, `.first` with proper handling of the `nil` case is the way to go. If you're going to force unwrap (`!`) or fail silently, raw indexing is probably the better way to go